# No colours in legend when using zero handlelength with colours from a colourmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, colormap

I'm trying to plot multiple lines, using the colours from the viridis colourmap. I want to set the `handlelength=0` in the legend, and when I do, the legend is now totally blank. If I don't mess around with `handlelength`, then it works fine (so the legend reads with the value, and then a line in the correct colour). And this works if I set the colours individually (so `c='C'+str(i)` for example).

Code below. matplotlib version is 3.6.2., pytho is 3.9.13

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

energy = np.linspace(40., 75., 36)
einds = np.linspace(0, 35, 8).astype(int)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(4,3), dpi=150)
for i in range(0, len(einds)):
    ax.plot(energy, energy+i, c=plt.cm.viridis([einds[i]/einds.max()]),
            label='{:.0f}keV'.format(energy[einds[i]]))
ax.grid()
leg=ax.legend(handlelength=0, handletextpad=0, fancybox=1,
              framealpha=1, loc='upper right', labelcolor='linecolor')
for item in leg.legendHandles:
    item.set_visible(False)
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm an idiot. Simple syntax error. Should have been

```
for i in range(0, len(einds)):
    ax.plot(energy, energy+i, c=plt.cm.viridis(einds[i]/einds.max()),
            label='{:.0f}keV'.format(energy[einds[i]]))
```

No square brackets in the call to the colormap.

Edit: corect graph included - thanks to gboffi for the idea.

[image]

Comment: Would you please post the correct plot?

Comment: Your treatment of the legend is intriguing. Thank you for posting the plot!

Comment: `for item in leg.legendHandles: item.set_visible(False)` seems a duplicate of `handlelength=0` - I've removed the loop and, apparently, nothing has changed.

Comment: @gboffi yes, in some cases I found I can remove that loop, however I have some instances of this where that hasn't worked. I've never looked into it closely enough to work out what the difference is, so I tend to include it just in case.